# How to use QLPreviewPanel?

Tags: objective-c, macos, quicklook

I have an app which can download images and text, I want to use the QLPreviewPanel to give a preview of this. However the delegate and datasource implementation has me confused. I just want to pass an image or string and have it displayed? (is QLPreviewPanel even the right thing to use here?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much to it. Take a look at Apple's sample project [Quick Look Downloader](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/QuickLookDownloader/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009082); the file MyDocument.m has the data source and delegate methods.

The data source methods are just like table view data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewPanel:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel
{
    return [myCollectionOfItems count];
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewPanel:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [myCollectionOfItems objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

You can skip implementing a delegate if you don't need to customize the behavior of the panel.

Comment: It seems a lot of fuss just preview something. And I don't understand the number of items/index. Surely theres only one thing display, unlike a table view where there are many rows.

Comment: The panel allows flipping through a list of previews. You can return whatever you want from these methods; return 1 from `numberOfPreviewItems...` and then whatever single item you like from `previewPanel:previewItem...`

Comment: Except the returned preview item has to follow `QLPreviewItem` and the item has to be an URL, when I just have the image as an NSImage.

Comment: @Jonathan Right...the preview panel is for files, not objects in memory.

Comment: I've now changed how the app works to avoid this, but thanks anyway